# Rails: best way to start an app with multiples models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, migration

I want to create a Rails app but I have a question before start it.

I have defined a database model in paper (about 15 tables) and I don't know which is the best way to start the application:

- Create the tables on database with my database client and after that in console do:

  ```
  rake db:schema:dump
  ```

  with this I will obtain the shema.rb and after that do a :

  ```
  rake db:migrate
  ```

or

- In console, one to one, create the models, edit them with an editor and do:

  ```
  rake db:migrate
  ```

I think the first one is more quickly but the second I think is better from the point of view of rails.

I am bit confused about that, can anyone help me with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails mean the only sure way to create a database for a new application - migration.
You can create a single migration for all of your application but such migration is not easy to roll back.
Therefore wise to create a migration for each table.
Normal situation when you have 100,500 migrations in the end. For that you get your application is ready for deploy to combat server.
Permitted the creation of migration through model and scaffold or independently.

Comment: Migration all the way

Comment: Thank you for your answers, so, the second way is the best way to start.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a generator?

```
rails g model User first_name last_name age:integer email user_name
```

You don't need to specify type if it's string. This will generate model class and migration.

Comment: I think for the second choice he means doing that and calling the rake migrate command

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be varying viewpoints on this issue.

Also, it depends if you're using the rails built-in sqlite database.

However, assuming that you do use the default rails db configurations,

I personally prefer the second choice.

Later, you might want to change some parts in your tables.

If you follow the rails way of doing so, this process will be very easy and less confusing.

Also, you can always add custom ruby scripts for pre-loading with data.

Of course, other people might find the other way easier.